# Optics zoom lens elements

Tags: optics

How would I go about designing an optical zoom lens configuration that gives me around 25x zoom eg 10mm to 250mm within a package of roughly 100-150mm?

Is there a good software or calculator/optimiser that can give me a better idea on what lenses to use and what refractive index for the elements or is it a case of playing around with different setups on phydemo for example?

I've used the paraxial ray tracing calculations and matrix methods for determining EFL of multiple lenses, is there a mathematical way to do this too, rather than trial and error of playing with different lenses?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.